# Domain universal url rewrite regex to change 2nd level domains to include www

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with redirect rule that would work universally on all 2nd level domains to redirect to WWW and I'm struggling with regular expression. There are many topics but they all suggest using named domain, I'm sure it can be done better.

Here is what I have so far: http://regexr.com/393vp

Edit:
Apparently link to 3rd party editor isn't enough for question to not be off-topic. Regex I needed had to match

```
domain.tld
2nddomain.tld
another-domain.tld
```

But not

```
www.domain.tld
one.domain.tld
one.two.domain.tld
```

Comment: When asking such questions it helps to provide samples of input with expected output.

Comment: I would be great if you can share some inputs and  expected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i couldn't get it to work well on your example data when using the multiline option, but if you feed each line individually then this will match the ones that need to have "www." prepended to them:

```
^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$
```

it's just the beginning of the line, infinitely many non-dots, a single dot, infinitely-many non-dots, and then the end of the line.

Comment: Yeah it quirks in the regexr, but it works in my environment since i feed it just single domain (just had to add capturing group to entire expression for replacement to work). Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)[^.]+\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,NE,L,R]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: It's domain specific "exmaple.com", not what I want, I need it universal for any domain.